# How to duplicate variables into template with phpWord and using cloneBlock

Tags: php, phpword

Using phpWord in my application, I try to clone a block in the template like this :

```
${CLONEME} <br>
     You may also notice that there’s one text break (empty paragraph) before this one that can be created also by PHPWord ${item}" <br>
${/CLONEME}
```

**Doing this in my php code :** `$document->cloneBlock('CLONEME', 2}`

**I obtain :**

> "  You may also notice that there’s one text break (empty paragraph)
>   before this one that can be created also by PHPWord ${item} 
>  You
>   may also notice that there’s one text break (empty paragraph) before
>   this one that can be created also by PHPWord ${item}   "

but `${item}` don't duplicate.

I want to have :

> "  You may also notice that there’s one text break (empty paragraph)
>   before this one that can be created also by PHPWord ${item#1}     You
>   may also notice that there’s one text break (empty paragraph) before
>   this one that can be created also by PHPWord ${item#2}   "

How can I do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see 2 possibilities:

1. extend the `cloneBlock` method to do what you want (or write your own) - and have a look at the `cloneRow` method to see how they're doing the `{item}->{item#1}` replacement
2. just live with multiple `{item}`-tags after `cloneBlock` and do several calls to `setValue($search, $replace, 1)`, limiting the replacements to one at a time

Hope that helps...