# Replacing content of block after generating clones using cloneBlock - PHPWord

Tags: php, mysql, phpword

Please can somebody be so kind to show me the syntax for using cloneblock in phpword.

So Ive got data in a MySQL DB, and for the single rows that I need to import into my word doc via phpword it works fine....to run my query and search and replace with template processor. BUT, now I want to insert multiple rows into my word document. I've researched and found that the cloneblock method is the answer. However I cannot get it working....currently my code runs but it doesn't seem to get to the second row.

I actually dnt get any error messages. My code executes fine...but the end display word file doesn't display fine....and if you see my code I got an echo statement...which echo's out in my browser exactly what I want "damaged" &"good", (as an example given of one of the row data) but that data doesn't get pulled into my word doc like that...it duplicates "damaged" , "damaged". .

```
$group_key=1;

do {    

  //loop to increase my uuid  - ($repeatgroup')
  $repeatgroup = $id."/"."trailer_repeat_group"."[".$group_key."]";

// query string
  $trailer_repeat_grouping = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM trailer_repeat_group LEFT JOIN main on trailer_repeat_group.PARENT_KEY = main.metainstanceID WHERE trailer_repeat_group.KEY_id = '$repeatgroup'");

  $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('CLONEME', $trailer_count);

  while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($trailer_repeat_grouping)) {    

    //this echo below I am using to test exactly what happends – independent of 
    //PHPword/templateprocessor
    echo $rttc =  $row1['right_trailer_tyre_condition'];

    //inserting  / searching / inserting values
    $templateProcessor->setValue("right_trailer_tyre_condition", $rttc);
  }

  // ending of loop / checking loop

  $group_key++;

} while ($group_key <= $trailer_count);
```

Comment: _Pro Tip:_ You will always get a better response from the community if you show us the actual code you are using

Comment: Examples is in Samples folder of repo: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples  and cloneBlock example is here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_23_TemplateBlock.php   it's enough documented with comments above every statement

Comment: Did you read this [existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362945/how-to-duplicate-variables-into-template-with-phpword-and-using-cloneblock)

Comment: Please put Your code in Your question that does not work

Comment: $group_key=1;

do {
        
$repeatgroup = $id."/"."trailer_repeat_group"."[".$group_key."]";


$trailer_repeat_grouping = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM trailer_repeat_group LEFT JOIN main on trailer_repeat_group.PARENT_KEY = main.metainstanceID WHERE trailer_repeat_group.KEY_id = '$repeatgroup'");

$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('CLONEME', mysqli_num_rows($trailer_repeat_grouping));


$templateProcessor>setValue("right_trailer_tyre_condition",$row['Left _tyre_condition'], 1);

$group_key++;
    } while ($group_key <= $trailer_count);

Comment: Hope the above code makes sense to you guys.

Comment: @num8er , yes I did. However it doesn't really show what I want to do, which is insert text/images into my template. The sample only shows deleting text between the tags.

Comment: @ClintonP I don't see any logical or something other issue about `cloneBlock`. Instead of 2 things: 1. while I was editing Your code I saw that You've written: `$templateProcessor>setValue` which should be `$templateProcessor->setValue` , 2. `$row['Left _tyre_condition']` - I don't see where did You get that `$row` variable. can You check it?

Comment: @num8er Hi...myapologies. Please see. I have rewritten My code above, in the original question...I've added in comments aswell. However know I've got a bit more progress. But let's take a specific uuid that's needs to generate this word. file. It has 2 unique rows of data...so I need to see 2 unique values in my word file....however it gets merged through but duplicating the first value....so I need to see "damaged" and 2nd row or line "good", but instead I see damaged , damaged. So it actually isn't looping it seems. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @ClintonP could You add to Your question whole line of error message with details? Cause in Your code I cannot see place where You're passing object to somewhere which is waiting for string. `object of class could not be converted to string`

Comment: @num8er Hi,  I actually dnt get any error messages. My code executes fine...but the end display word file doesn't display fine....and if you see my code I got an echo statement...which echo's out in my browser exactly what I want "damaged" &"good", but that data doesn't get pulled into my word doc like that...it duplicates "damaged" , "damaged". .

Comment: @num8er original question has been edited accordingly

Comment: @num8er yes...using xampp, phpmyadmin, query executes fine...and I can see rows....that I need, and I know for a fact my query is right, because the echo throws statement throws out the right row data

Comment: @ClintonP I think when You do `->setValue` it replaces all field that has defined key. So what about defining some number `right_trailer_tyre_condition1`, `right_trailer_tyre_condition2` ...

Comment: @num8er please can you show me what you mean....I thought the search variable inside setvalue must be static....as it will just repeat it and populate it according to what ever rows it has coming to it.

Comment: @ClintonP I've found solution to Your issue and wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done investigation and found the solution.

You're **cloning** same blocks **N times**:

```php
$templateProcessor->cloneBlock('CLONEME', $trailer_count);
```

and then by doing fetch You're trying to replace `right_trailer_tyre_condition` with some value:

```
$templateProcessor->setValue("right_trailer_tyre_condition", $rttc);
```

Issue is that You're **replacing** **all placeholders**.

But in fact You **need to replace** them **one** by one with **different** values.

Solution is to define **3rd argument** that means **count of items to replace**.

Simply change it to be:

```
$templateProcessor->setValue("right_trailer_tyre_condition", $rttc, 1);
```

Comment: Hi..I have tried that...however when a 1 is added it only populates the first clone block and not the second..., if I change it to a 2, then it populates the second aswell. Thanks alot for pointing this out to me. You did help. However I am opening a new question. I am having the same issue with images. It duplicates it through the clone block.